# Code CleaningTip

Tags: c#, arrays

Is there any way to clean up this function, i need to clean the code of this function because every time i have to intialize the  array index and give it its values, Is there any way i can clean up this function? Every time i am doing the same thing just changing the columnId value, Column and value of the class

```
private static GovernmentalSearchResult[] GetGovernmentalSearchResults(Result result)
        {
            GovernmentalSearchResult [] returnResult = new GovernmentalSearchResult[10];
            returnResult[0] = new GovernmentalSearchResult();
            returnResult[0].SearchMetadataColumnId = (int)SearchMetadataColumnEnum.Duns;
            returnResult[0].SearchMetadataColumn=SearchMetadataColumnEnum.Duns;
            returnResult[0].Value=result.duns;

            returnResult[1] = new GovernmentalSearchResult();
            returnResult[1].SearchMetadataColumnId = (int)SearchMetadataColumnEnum.legalBusinessName;
            returnResult[1].SearchMetadataColumn = SearchMetadataColumnEnum.legalBusinessName;
            returnResult[1].Value = result.legalBusinessName;


            returnResult[2] = new GovernmentalSearchResult();
            returnResult[2].SearchMetadataColumnId = (int)SearchMetadataColumnEnum.CageCode;
            returnResult[2].SearchMetadataColumn = SearchMetadataColumnEnum.CageCode;
            returnResult[2].Value = result.cage;


            returnResult[3] = new GovernmentalSearchResult();
            returnResult[3].SearchMetadataColumnId = (int)SearchMetadataColumnEnum.City;
            returnResult[3].SearchMetadataColumn = SearchMetadataColumnEnum.City;
            returnResult[3].Value = result.samAddress.city;


            returnResult[4] = new GovernmentalSearchResult();
            returnResult[4].SearchMetadataColumnId = (int)SearchMetadataColumnEnum.Country;
            returnResult[4].SearchMetadataColumn = SearchMetadataColumnEnum.Country;
            returnResult[4].Value = result.samAddress.country;


            returnResult[5] = new GovernmentalSearchResult();
            returnResult[5].SearchMetadataColumnId = (int)SearchMetadataColumnEnum.DelinquentFederalDebt;
            returnResult[5].SearchMetadataColumn = SearchMetadataColumnEnum.DelinquentFederalDebt;
            returnResult[5].Value = result.hasDelinquentFederalDebt.ToString();

            returnResult[6] = new GovernmentalSearchResult();
            returnResult[6].SearchMetadataColumnId = (int)SearchMetadataColumnEnum.StateProvince;
            returnResult[6].SearchMetadataColumn = SearchMetadataColumnEnum.StateProvince;
            returnResult[6].Value = result.samAddress.stateOrProvince;

            returnResult[7] = new GovernmentalSearchResult();
            returnResult[7].SearchMetadataColumnId = (int)SearchMetadataColumnEnum.ZipCode;
            returnResult[7].SearchMetadataColumn = SearchMetadataColumnEnum.ZipCode;
            returnResult[7].Value = result.samAddress.zip;

            return returnResult;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function to return `GovernmentalSearchResult`. You can also use `Func<>` instead.

```
    public GovernmentalSearchResult CreateGovernmentalSearchResult(SearchMetadataColumnEnum searchMetadataColumnEnum, string value)
    {
        return new GovernmentalSearchResult
       {
           SearchMetadataColumnId = (int)searchMetadataColumnEnum,
           SearchMetadataColumn = searchMetadataColumnEnum,
           Value = value
       };
    }
```

Then you can call it in your code like:

```
GovernmentalSearchResult [] returnResult = new GovernmentalSearchResult[10];
returnResult[0] = CreateGovernmentalSearchResult(SearchMetadataColumnEnum.Duns, result.duns);
```